# Is the anecdote about Niels Bohr keeping a horseshoe on his door true?

Tags: biographical-details, debunking, depiction-of-scientists

I recently came to know of an anecdote about Niels Bohr that [the philosopher Slavoj Zizek claims to have read in a biography of Bohr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTAp3KZwYl0). He doesn't specify the author or the biography.

The anecdote goes as follows: Bohr used to keep a horseshoe on the door of his house. In European (and Indian) superstitions, the horseshoe is believed to be an object that guards the house against the evil spirits. A friend, upon seeing the horseshoe on the door of Bohr's house, asked Bohr as to whether he subscribed to the relevant superstitions. Bohr replied that he didn't believe in them but he was told that the horseshoe works whether or not one believes in their power.

I tried to find an authentic historical account of the story but I could only find sparsely sourced articles which only claimed the story to be an anecdote. Is there an authentic historical account of the story being either true or false? Thanks!

Comment: I would Google Scholar and Google Books. Just found this article Quotable physics
Seweryn Chomet 2008 Phys. World 21 (03) 38. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2058-7058/21/03/37/meta

Comment: @M.Farooq Thanks! It's an interesting article. But, nonetheless, it claims the story to be an anecdote.

Comment: It is very difficult to trace quotes. Historical research is very layered, you start from a recent reference and move back to older references finally going to the oldest. I was looking for a quote from Max Planck, it took me six month to locate it. It was in German and the English version was highly distorted. Most references even in books were wrong. See this page, it investigates the very first appearance of Bohr's quote. https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/09/horseshoe-luck/

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, I realize the issue. I think Bohr's son is still alive and active--maybe one can mail him. :P

Comment: Really? I was not aware of that. Often children have little interest in their parent's achievements.

Comment: @M.Farooq Haha ;) I was mistaken actually--his son, Aage Bohr (also a Nobel winning physicist) actually died in 2009. I had his grandson, Tomas Bohr in mind who is also a physicist and is active. Quanta Magazine recently covered his work on the double-slit experiment in the context of the pilot-wave theory (which he disproved ;)). Here: https://www.quantamagazine.org/videos/tomas-bohr/

Comment: Excellent genes, I must say. Two centuries of physics!

Comment: This joke is told about many people in various versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One can spot a fabricated story by a number of tells: absence of the original citation, shifty dates (in Heisenberg's version, Bohr was telling it in 1927), proliferation of mutually exclusive details (in some versions, the horseshoe was over Bohr's desk). As for the origin, aside from Kenyon's and Droke's popular retellings of 1956, linked in the comments, we read the following in [Samuel Goudsmit's editorial Bias (Physical Review Letters 25 (1970) 419-20)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.25.419):

> "*There  are still  authors  who believe  that  referees   and editors are biased   against them. We doubt  that  they  can be convinced  that  this  is not so. A  necessary  condition for being  a  successful  research  worker is  a  touch  of paranoia... I  have  known  a few physicists  who lack  this  essential  trait.   When  someone  publishes  their  results,   they  take  it as proof   that  their  work  was  worthwhile  and they are  happy to start  on something  else... I did not feel  it  that  way at all.   Unfortunately  I  could  not blame  any referees  or  editors  for  having been  scooped;  instead  I  just  blamed  my stars... **In my study hangs  a  fine old  horse  shoe,  which  I found  in an abandoned  Western ghost  town.  I don't  believe  in superstitions, but it is  supposed  to work  even for  a nonbeliever$^2\!\!$. It hasn't  so far.***
>
> $^2$*For  historians:  This  fact was  conveyed to me in  1941 by I. Bernard Cohen, the historian of science  at Harvard University. I passed it  on to  Niels  Bohr in  1954 when he visited Brookhaven.   It  is  now known as  "Bohr's story". W. Heisenberg,  in his  book Der  Teil  und  das  Gauze,  incorrectly has  Bohr telling it  already in 1927.*"

The irony. Those interested in Goudsmit can consult [Bederson' scientific biography](http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/goudsmit-samuel.pdf), but the story would lose its gloss without Bohr's name in it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you somehow dig up all this or did you know the crucial bits already? Thanks for the amazing answer! :-)

Comment: @DvijMankad I vaguely remembered Heisenberg's mention, which gives the story some plausibility. But my fakery radar was flashing, so I looked further. Finding Bederson's memoir was a bit of luck.